# Closure of subset of the space of sequences converging to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be the space of sequences $(a_n)$ that converge to zero, equipped with the sup norm. Consider the subsets:

$Y =\{(a_n): a_{2n-1} = 0, n = 1, 2, \dots \}$ and $Z =\{(a_n): a_{2n} = n^2a_{2n - 1}, n = 1, 2, \dots \}$.

I want to show that the element $x = (1, 0, \frac{1}{4}, 0, \frac{1}{9}, 0, \dots)$ lies in the closure of $Y+Z$.

Since the closure of the set is the union of the set itself and the set of its limit points, we can firstly show that $x$ is not in $Y+Z$ (this is quite trivial, I have already done that) and then that $x$ is a limit point of $Y+Z$. This is the part where I get confused, especially since we are working in the sup norm. How are we supposed to approach this? I assume giving an example would be enough, but I don't know how to come up with it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\delta_n$ be the sequence with a $1$ at the $n$-th place and $0$'s everywhere else.

For any $n\in\mathbb N$,
$$x_n:=-\sum_{k=1}^n\delta_{2k}+\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1{k^2}\delta_{2k-1}+\delta_{2k}\right)\in Y+Z$$
and $x=\lim x_n.$